# Multiselect autocomplete textbox not working properly

Tags: php, mysqli

code:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        function split( val ) {
            return val.split( /,\s*/ );
        }
        function extractLast( term ) {
            return split( term ).pop();
        }
        $( "#company" ).bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            minLength: 1,
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.getJSON("company-skills.php", { term : extractLast( request.term )},response);
            },
            focus: function() {
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = split( this.value );
                terms.pop();
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                terms.push( "" );
                this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                return false;
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="text" name="company" id="company" placeholder="Job title, skills or company" class="form-control">

<?php
    include('config.php'); 
    $query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC;";
    $query .= "SELECT key FROM skill WHERE key LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY key ASC;";

    mysqli_multi_query($con,$query);
    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $data[] = $row['company_name'];
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result);
    mysqli_next_result($con);

    $result = mysqli_store_result($con);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $data[] = $row['key'];
    }  
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

In this code I have create a multiselect autocomplete textbox where when I write something inside the textbox it always start words with "A" whether I start with "B" or any alphabet for example: If I want to write TATA it showing result with "A" letter I do't know why ?. So how can I fix this issue ?Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

On your first query:

```
$query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company_name LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC;";
```

you sorted the `company_name` by `ASC`. you can remove the `ORDER BY company_name ASC` on you query. also this kind of query doesn't have any relevance points, so the  result may not be the one that you wanted.

Comment: I have remove as you say but still its not working :(

Comment: did you also remove the order on the skill table query? like i said, sql doesnt have a relevance algorithm to show the best result. the result will depend on your data. its better to use a third party like algolia, maybe you are trying to do something like this. https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/search-ui/autocomplete/auto-complete/

Answer (score 0):

Change the query:
So now if you start with `A` only those company will show have name start with 'A'

For more details about this: [Mysql LIKE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
$query = "SELECT company_name FROM company WHERE company_name LIKE $searchTerm."%' ORDER BY company_name ASC;";
```

Comment: I am trying your answer @DsRaj but still nothing change

Comment: paste the output in the answer which you want?